Conditionally loading Jotai devtools styles in devmode only
I started to use Jotai instead Recoil with devtools. Devtools in Jotai has own style, to use this style I need to import it like this:
import 'jotai-devtools/styles.css';

In docs of Jotai says: "Note that this may get included in your production builds. Please import it conditionally if you want to avoid that"
And I don't know how to do that in best way.
I'm using Vite in my project.
Please, help
